# Keras model creation for two networks - are networks shared or not?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Given the following code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Add, Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

X = Flatten(input_shape=input_shape)(X_input)
X = Dense(512, activation="elu", kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(X)

action = Dense(action_space, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(X)
value = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(X)

Actor = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = action)
Actor.compile(loss=ppo_loss, optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=lr))

Critic = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = value)
Critic.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=lr))

Actor.fit(...)
Critic.predict(...)
```

Are Actor and Critic seperate networks or do i partially fit `Critic` with `Actor.fit()`?

Comment: The models are the same in both structure and weights even after training first model on data and although you have defined the second model before training on data. it's just cause of objects characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network `Critic` and `Actor` share same networks for most of the part, except the last layer where `Actor` has `action` layer and `Critic` has `value` layer. This can be visible when you do a `Actor.summary()` compared to `Critic.summary()`. See below.

```
Actor.summary()
Model: "model_8"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_8 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784)]             0         
                                                                 
 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 784)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_16 (Dense)            (None, 512)               401920    
                                                                 
 dense_17 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 513       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 402,433
Trainable params: 402,433
Non-trainable params: 0

Critic.summary()
Model: "model_9"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_8 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784)]             0         
                                                                 
 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 784)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_16 (Dense)            (None, 512)               401920    
                                                                 
 dense_18 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 513       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 402,433
Trainable params: 402,433
Non-trainable params: 0
```

You can see the first three layers have represented with the same name, therefore are same objects in the memory. This can be also verified when you do a `layer[n].get_weights()`. This should provide you same weights for identical layer in both networks.

So when you fit on `Actor`, except the last layer, the weights of the other layers get adjusted, which also effects the `Critic`. But the last layer for `Critic` is not trained yet and therefore when you do `Crtic.predict()` your predictions are not as per training done on `Actor`.

So yes you partially fit `Critic` with `Actor.fit()`.